# Java Display Text On Right Side of Text Area

Tags: java, swing, text, orientation, right-to-left

The problem I have with `ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT` is that characters such as '/' or '!' or '.' are shown on the left side.

I just need text to be drawn from right to left but using standard, western, English left to right notation for text characters.

Is this possible without manually rendering text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't generating your issue, can you please use my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for shown on the left side.

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class RightToLeft {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JTextArea text = new JTextArea(10, 5);
                text.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                text.setText("one/\n "
                        + "!two\n"
                        + ".three\n"
                        + "/four\n"
                        + "five!\n"
                        + "six.\n"
                        + "seven\n"
                        + "eight\n");
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("العنوان بالعربي");
                frame.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants text like `"one/"` to appear right-aligned but laid out in left-to-right flow.

Comment: I got it to work using JTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT)` for the text field.