# Hebrew text in JTextField (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, hebrew

When I do something like `fileText.setText(path)` in a `JTextField`, it works well unless the text is in Hebrew (or combines English and Hebrew). Then I get something like this:

[image]

I tried different fonts (even fonts that "Hebrew" is mentioned in them), but it didn't help. How do I fix it?

By the way, it is working properly with the ToolTipText (`fileText.setToolTipText(path)`)

Here's my code:

```
// browse files or folders
    public void browse(JTextField txtField) {

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));     

        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedDir = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String path = selectedDir.getAbsolutePath();

            if (txtField == srcText) {
                srcText.setText(path); 
                srcText.setToolTipText(path); 
            }
            else {
                if (txtField == dstText) {
                    dstText.setText(path); 
                    dstText.setToolTipText(path);
                }
                }}
    }
```

Comment: What kind of JDK are you using ?

Comment: *"I tried different fonts (even fonts that "Hebrew" is mentioned in them) .."* See [`Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Maybe this BUG is relevant to your case : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133246

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I tried and I don't have any problem, post your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added it.

Comment: Are you setting the [`RUN_DIRECTION`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/bidi.html)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried it. It didn't help

Comment: I still have no trouble. Please post a proper [mcve], include the exact string path you that gives you the problem. Add the information of your JDK version and your OS.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, since your code works well as it is. Please try to your environment.

For me it works flawlessly out of the box with the default font on Windows 7. Java JDK1.8.0_31

```
public class JTextFieldExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JTextFieldExample() {
        super("TextField Test Demo");
        final Container container = getContentPane();
        final JTextField textField=new JTextField("hello \u05DD\u05D5\u05DC\u05E9 Hello \u05DD\u05D5\u05DC\u05E9"); 
        // optionally set RTL
        textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        container.add(textField);
        setSize(300,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        new JTextFieldExample();
    }
}
```

Makes a window with a JTextField containing:

> hello םולש Hello םולש

(I am sorry if I am using something strange or offensive in Hebrew. I just copied the unicode chars from another page, they claim it means "hello").

I've also tried you code in a test app and that is worked well, too.
Also Hebrew-only, English-Hebrew mixtures work well.

However you may prefer to set the RTL orientation to better match to Hebrew, and I guess in my example, the Hebrew letters are displayed in reverse order disregarding to the actual orientation.

Do the following:

- check if the JTextField work well in Hebrew? If so, then there is something odd in the path returned by the file selector
- check the path by priting it to the console. Locate chars which can cause problems, e.g. \-es, or broken unicode code points
- dump the bytes of the string in hexa. This can reveal e.g. unicode byte ordering marks or broken unicode code points.

Comment: I tend to put a notice on the top along the lines of "This is not an answer yet, but a comment with a lot of code and details" for this type of post to avoid the Not An Answer flag.

Comment: The answer is that the problem could not be reproduced with Java 8 and Windows 7, therefore the original code in question works well.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's an observation. You do not instruct the OP how to fix or work around their current problem. Finally, you are asking the OP a question in your answer which further invalidates it as an answer. See my comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509414/hebrew-text-in-jtextfield-swing/35588736?noredirect=1#comment58821206_35509414) abd [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509414/hebrew-text-in-jtextfield-swing/35588736?noredirect=1#comment58854173_35509414).

Comment: True. The problem can not be reproduced, which makes it tricky to fix. I think the problem is in the path returned by the underlying OS, but that is an _assumption_. I tried to do my best to help solving the problem, and given some hints what to do.

Comment: I didn't say that anything you did is wrong. If you read my initial comment again, I suggested you "protect" your "answer" by adding a notice to it explaining what it's trying to do. If you are flagged as Not An Answer your post will just be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I put there that "not an answer".

Comment: The Hebrew output of the proposed solution is reversed, the `setComponentOrientation` function alone does not behave properly (please refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659133/java-display-text-on-right-side-of-text-area#9659309), usage of `JTextField#setHorizontalAlignment` is preferred.